# ZIP file - Incorrect entry name encoding when open with Windows Explorer

Tags: java, compression

I create a zip file using code bellow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    String inputFilepath = "./src/main/resources/email-hule.html";
    String outputFilepath = "." + File.separator + "target" + File.separator + "ĐỨcNguyễn.zip";
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ZipOutputStream zos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFilepath);
        zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry("Đức Nguyễn Văn.xml");
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFilepath);

        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        zos.closeEntry();
        //remember close it
        zos.close();
        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
}
```

Full code [here](https://github.com/vanduc1102/JavaExampleMaven/blob/master/src/main/java/my/example/java/core/ZipFileApp.java)

If I open the file with 7zip

[image: Open Zipe file with 7zip]

But I open the file with Windows Explorer - Windows 7

[image: Open Zipe file with Windows Explorer]

How can I correct it?

Thanks

Comment: I tried with Apache common compress. But it is still the same. [source-here](https://github.com/vanduc1102/JavaExampleMaven/blob/master/src/main/java/my/example/java/core/ZipFileTestApacheCommon.java)

Comment: After trying with OneDrive, GoogleDrive .... They both not supported,... It is because of Windows 7 Explorer, lack of support for UTF-8